# Download Stops When Dismissing ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using the [Cheapjack Library (iOS)](https://github.com/timbueno/Cheapjack) to download files inside my app in Swift. I queue the download from another class. This seems to work fine, the download gets queued and starts to download. However when the "DownloadsViewController",where the downloads happen, is not shown,  when the file finishes downloading it does not execute the didiFinishDownload block. Any ideas on how I could handle my error.
Also when I open the Downloads ViewController and the dismiss it, the download hangs where it was when I dismissed the ViewController
 Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
//Adding download from another class
let downloadItem = DownloadsTableViewCellItem(identifier: identifier, urlString: url3, infoLabelTitle: info, stateLabelTitle: "Downloading...", progressLabelTitle: "", action: DownloadsTableViewCellAction.Pause)
        DownloadsViewController().addDownloadItem(downloadItem, withIdentifier: identifier)

//Receiving download in DownloadsViewController
func addDownloadItem(downloadItem: DownloadsTableViewCellItem, withIdentifier identifier: CheapjackFile.Identifier) {

        downloadItems[identifier] = downloadItem
        identifiers.append(identifier)

        CheapjackManager.sharedManager.download(downloadItem.url(), identifier: identifier)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

//DidFinishBlock
func cheapjackManager(manager: CheapjackManager, didFinishDownloading withSession: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, url: NSURL, forFile file: CheapjackFile) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("Did finish downloading file")
        SongsTableViewController().tableView.reloadData()

            let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let documentsPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0]
            print("DocumentsPath: \(documentsPath)")
        let randomUUID: String = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".mp3"
        let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/" + randomUUID)
            print("DestinationPath: \(destinationPath)")


            if (!filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationPath as String)) {

                let url1 = file.request.URL
                print("URL1: \(url1)")
                print("Temp Loc: \(String(url))")

                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

                if (data != nil) {



                        data!.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: false)
                       //data!.writeToURL(NSURL(string:destinationPath)!, atomically: false)

                            print("The music files has been saved.")


                        let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)

                        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Track")
                        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "url = %@", String(url1!))

                        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

                        do {

                            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

                            fetchResults = results as! [NSManagedObject]

                            if fetchResults.count != 0 {

                                let managedObject = fetchResults[0]
                                managedObject.setValue(destinationPath, forKey: "fileURL")

                                appDel.saveContext()

                                SongsTableViewController().fetchData()

                            } else {

                                print("No track found")
                            }

                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }

                }
            } else {
                print("The files already exist")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you set delegate of CheapjackManager.sharedManager to `DownloadsViewController`?

Comment: @user3480295 Yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DownloadsViewController` would be deinit if you dismiss it.

Note that `delegate` of `CheapjackManager` is `weak`. After you dismiss `DownloadsViewController`, `delegate` will be set to nil, any call to `delegate` will be ignored, including `cheapjackManager:didiFinishDownload:`.

Meanwhile, `CheapjackManager` is still downloading resource for you. Just can't observe it in `DownloadsViewController`.

Comment: Can I avoid the deinit call?

Comment: Try to set delegate to some other instance, such as`AppDelegate`.